# Keep the correct value item in a listview using AsyncTask

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, picasso

I'm a newbie using android and I'm facing a problem when I'm trying to display a list of images together with a button for each image. The event when pressing the button is to display the url of the image. So,  when i do scroll on the screen, the new images displayed have different url when pressing their buttons. These values matching the same as the first images displayed before scrolling on the screen.

My main code is as follows:

```
public class ImagenesAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context mContext;
private Map<String,?> mListImagenes;

static class ViewHolder{
    public Button buttonHolder;
    public ImageView imageviewHolder;
    int position;
}

public ImagenesAdapter(Context c, Map<String,?> list) {
    mContext = c;
    mListImagenes = list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mListImagenes.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mListImagenes.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // reference to convertView
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder=null;
    final int posicion=position;

    // inflate new layout if null
    if(v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listado_imagenes_subidas, null);

        //configure view holder
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.buttonHolder = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnCopiarImagenUrl);
        viewHolder.imageviewHolder = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
        viewHolder.buttonHolder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CopiarImagenListado(posicion);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Imagen copiada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        v.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
    }

    SharedPreferences prefsTH = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PrefsTH", ListadoImagenesSubidasMain.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String cadenaURL="";
    String sp = prefsTH.getString("urlTH"+position, "");
    if (sp != "")
    {
        cadenaURL = sp;

        if ((viewHolder.imageviewHolder != null) && (cadenaURL != "")){
            viewHolder.position = position;
            new DownloadAsyncTask(viewHolder, position).execute(cadenaURL);
        }
    }
    return v;
}

private class DownloadAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    private ViewHolder mHolder;
    private int mPosition;

    public DownloadAsyncTask(ViewHolder holder, int position){
        this.mHolder = holder;
        this.mPosition = position;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        dialog.setMessage("Cargando imágenes...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = params[0];

        return url;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (result != null && mPosition == mHolder.position){
            mHolder.buttonHolder.setText("Copiar");

            Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(result)
            .into(mHolder.imageviewHolder);
        }

    }

private void CopiarImagenListado(int position){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);

    String cadenaURL="";
    String sp = prefs.getString("url"+position, "");
    if (sp != "")
    {
        cadenaURL = sp;
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)mContext.getSystemService(mContext.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Imagen copiada", sp);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
    }
}
```

What do i have to do for not to lose new data when displaying new images in the listview?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could your try this :

```
// inflate new layout if null
if(v == null)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listado_imagenes_subidas, null);

    //configure view holder
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.buttonHolder = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnCopiarImagenUrl);
    viewHolder.imageviewHolder = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
    v.setTag(viewHolder);
}
else
{
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
}

viewHolder.buttonHolder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        CopiarImagenListado(posicion);
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Imagen copiada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Even if the view is recycled, you have to redefined `onClick` as `posicion` is involved.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the position as the tag of the button and then read it in the onClickListener:

```
viewHolder.buttonHolder.setTag(posicion);
viewHolder.buttonHolder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CopiarImagenListado((Integer)v.getTag());
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Imagen copiada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: That's it. Why using setTag to assign the position of the item in the listview is a good choice? I mean that how the program knows what position has to resolve in the postexecute of the Asyntask class?

Comment: So that as you scroll the button always knows which item in the list it was associated with.  Otherwise, the way you had it before you would have mismatched image URLs.

Comment: With this code, there are some times that when i press a button of an image the url is wrong. Other times the value is correct but, randomly, other times when I scroll on the screen I get a wrong url.

Comment: can you post the code for this method as well: `CopiarImagenListado`